# How to handle exception with imap_unordered in python multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x

I am using pool.imap_unordered to apply a function over different txt files saved locally.

Is it possible to capture the exception and `pass`? 
If my code runs into an exception, it blocks the entire loop.

```
pool = Pool(processes=15)

results = {}
files = glob.glob('{}/10K_files/*.txt'.format(path_input))

for key, output in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_file, files),total=len(files)):
    results[key] = output
```

I've tried something like this:

```
pool = Pool(processes=15)

results = {}
files = glob.glob('{}/10K_files/*.txt'.format(path_input))

try:
    for key, output in tqdm(pool.imap_unordered(process_file, files), total=len(files)):
       results[key] = output
except:
    print("error")
```

but then I want to resume the loop from where I started.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You could catch the exception in process_file and return it. Then test for whether the return value is an exception. Here is an example:

```
import os
import traceback
import multiprocessing as mp


def main():
    work_items = [i for i in range(20)]
    pool = mp.Pool()
    for result in pool.imap_unordered(process_file_exc, work_items):
        if isinstance(result, Exception):
            print("Got exception: {}".format(result))
        else:
            print("Got OK result: {}".format(result))


def process_file_exc(work_item):
    try:
        return process_file(work_item)
    except Exception as ex:
        return Exception("Err on item {}".format(work_item)
                         + os.linesep + traceback.format_exc())


def process_file(work_item):
    if work_item == 9:
        # this will raise ZeroDivisionError exception
        return work_item / 0
    return "{} * 2 == {}".format(work_item, work_item * 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```